# Developing GIS Apps for Android: Java or Python?

Tags: java, android, python, gis

I am a newbie in android apps development. I was wondering which of the two is easier for developing android apps which are more geared towards GPS and GIS related data/activity.

I see python being predominently used for GIS related applications/programs. I have also heard/read that Python is easier to code and learn to code. In addition, I am not looking for an complicated applications other than simply logging acceleration, GPS data along with triggering camera activity.

What IDE would you suggest me based on your answer?
I was playing with Eclipse IDE for Java to develop some "Hello World Apps".

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640806/android-java-v-python) post seem to be old to me and the answers does not seem to consider the GIS aspects.

Comment: Contrarywise I would say that answer is sound- If you want to use the native Android stuff like image handling and GPS data you want the most native platform, so Java is intuitively the thing you are after. Ultimately which language you choose is a relatively inconsequential decision in the majority of cases, your architecture is far more important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is unless you have a highly compelling reason that has been peer-reviewed, do not fight the Android platform.  That means you should just use the standard Java Android APIs.

I've programmed a couple of apps that make use of the Android GPS hardware.  You will find many examples and guides using Java.

If you find some compelling reason to use python for your back-end of an enterprise system, that will still be possible.

As far as IDE advice, I prefer IntelliJ IDEA, having used both eclipse and IDEA.  Eclipse is great, though I find the IDEA UI and features to be easier to learn and use.  No doubt they are both fantastic and complicated software that will at times frustrate you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is Java as Java is Android's language.
There are other options like Mono with C#, Python, C++ with NDK, C++ with Marmalade, etc
Most official android docs are about java and C++ with NDK.

Python on Android is mostly used by python fans in rooted environment.
If you wish to make commercial and release it in Google Play market then you should use Java in such application.