# Best portable development platform for small personal project

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm looking for a development platform (language and set of libraries) that will allow me to develop a personal project. (In case anyone is curious, I'm looking at making a music library manager, similar to iTunes, that can work on multiple platforms and sync with Android devices).

I want the language to have the following characteristics:

**Essential**
The program must run flawlessly, with no (or very little) code changes on Mac, Linux, and Windows. That means, notably, that I need to have a cross-platform GUI framework, a consistent API for accessing files and directories, and a consistent interface for talking to USB storage devices

**Important**
A language that is easy to use, powerful, and expressive. Big standard libraries with a lot of built-in functionality. (I'd probably use C#/.NET but the portability isn't great)

**Nice to have**
Good tool support (on Linux if possible, but I'll do my development on Windows if needs be)
Not Java. (I have used it and just don't like it - I'm not interested in getting into a language war here).

Please help me choose a language!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Python

1. **Cross platform GUI**: [more than one option](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming), I'd use [WxPython](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WxPython), but Qt bindings are also available ([comparison between wxWidgets and Qt](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxWidgets_Compared_To_Other_Toolkits)).
2. **[File System API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)**: this gets into the `os` package, but there are also [convenience methods for just dealing with I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).
3. **USB I/O**: I confess to not having any knowledge here, but suspect if you're talking storage that Python will be able to read and write using its IO package.
4. **Libraries, Ease of Use, etc..**: there's a lot built in, but also [a huge number of add-ons](https://web.archive.org/web/20180415050937/https://pypi.python.org/pypi) (called "packages"). Some of the most notable are [SciPy](https://scipy.org/) and [NumPy](https://numpy.org/), used for scientific and numerical analysis.
5. **Tooling**: [there are a number of IDEs out there](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments), I use [PyDev](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyDev) (but it's Eclipse based so you probably won't like it if you don't like Java).

Finally, [Python is supported on Android via its scripting environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-on-android).

Comment: Accepting because this is the most complete answer, but in case anyone is curious I decided to go with C++/Qt.

Answer (score 2):

For cross platform GUI, you can explore [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/). The back-end can be on c.

Have you explored anything so far?

Answer (score 1):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) [quick](http://qt.nokia.com/products/qt-quick/) ?