# how to setup android-scripting + python on Android phones?

Tags: android, python, android-scripting

I've downloaded the latest available version of python interpreter [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/downloads/list). Now, how can i start scripting in python on my phone? The apk (r4) that i've installed is has not any other option than download python interpreter and browse modules.

any help? What's next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now I figured out what i was doing wrong. On the user guide they didn't mention to download the [this file](http://android-scripting.googlecode.com/files/sl4a_r4.apk) before install the interpreter. They presume that the user has it installed and give you the link only for the interpreter, as you can see [here, on the user guide](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/UserGuide). So, i was not able to code anything.

Answer (score 0):

refer [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10940) or [here](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/7157/1) or to this popular question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-any-way-to-run-python-on-android).

Comment: you should see that I've already chosen a solution for my scripting, installed the platform and now I have a specific question about that platform. Thank's anyway for the links, but my question is about the platform that I mentioned on my question.