# python for android development without emulator

Tags: android, python, command-line, android-emulator

My laptop is rally showing it's age, and last night after trying out the android emulator (and having to wait half an hour for it to get past the startup screen) I began thinking that perhaps there is a better way to work with python and android.

I am aware that I could write code the mac, drop it into the phone and test it from there, but perhaps there is a better way? Can I use the emulator purely for debugging? - no gui ? Any ideas or experience?

Comment: I suppose upgrading the laptop is not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must see these links:

- [Is there a way to run Python on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-any-way-to-run-python-on-android)
- [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

There are useful discussion for your problem.