# Can you use GSUtil on android?

Tags: android, python, google-cloud-storage

Is is possible to use the Google Cloud Storage utility, gsutil, on android?  The requirements are a linux OS and python, so theoretically it is possible.  I do not know of a complete python port for android and have found [this post regarding python on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-any-way-to-run-python-on-android).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that even if by some miracle you could get it to work, it would be astronomically harder and more prone to breakage than just using the Cloud Storage API using [its client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Cloud_Storage_API).

The API is currently in Limited Availability, but you can request access through the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console).