# Embed Python in Java on Android

Tags: java, android, python

By embed I mean execute Python code from String in Java.

Jython won't compile for Android, and [Scripting Layer for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) doesn't seem to let me embed Python through my Java application.

So how to embed Python in a Java application on Android?

Comment: If you wanted to, you could also use [Ruby](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ruby/).

Comment: I don't see any question here.

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-any-way-to-run-python-on-android

Comment: check this out.. it might help you http://kivy.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look on [this](http://jepp.sourceforge.net/), it works for J2SE, you can try run on Android.