# How to convert .Py to .Apk

Tags: python, android, apk

I just want to know that, can we convert a python script into an android application.

for example:

```
#This is my python app

a = input("Enter your name: ")
print('\n Hi, ' + a)
```

This is just a simple python script with no gui (not needed), it will run on shell/cli mode, like Termux do.

```
> Enter your name: Who must not be named
```

```
> Hi, Who must not be named
```

Is it possible to convert above script into an apk file, without using any other modules etc.

Comment: I didn't test it but in Termux you can run `pkg install python` and you can run python script without converting to apk.

Comment: I tested it - `pkg install python` installs `python 3.10.4`

Comment: `.apk` usually means program created with Java - so it would need some tool which put Python with code to Java code - and this may need to install Java SDK and [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) so it needs many megabytes (gigabytes) of code. I don't know tool which can convert it directly to apk. but as I know GUI [kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) can generate code for Android

Comment: @furas, i appreciate your efforts, thanks for adding your comment, I was included termux as an example application. although i know about kivy library, however for mentioned python application , there is no GUI

Comment: if you will have application without GUI then you can't see results - Android will NOT open console to show it. To run it you will have to open `termux` (or other similar tool ie. [QPython3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qpython.qpy3&hl=pl&gl=US)). Or you will have to create application with GUI.

Comment: meanwhile I found this [Tools to run Python on Android.](https://medium.com/@umerfarooq_26378/tools-to-run-python-on-android-9060663972b4). Some tools creates application with GUI (like `kivy`) and others opens console and later you run code in this console (like `termux`)

Comment: checking tools from last link I think `chaquopy` is interesting. It can put Python console code inside Java App with some console -  [chaquopy-console](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy-console) - but first it needs a lot of instalation - Java, Android SDK, maybe Android Studio, buldozer, etc. and Chaquopy.

Answer (score 0):

An easy alternative
https://puravidaapps.com/skulpt.php since, working on [MIT App inventor](https://appinventor.mit.edu/) is way more easier then, developing a Android app on any other platform :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is my github repository for converting .py files to .apk files (Kivy library). If you want to run an app without the kivy library on Android, you can run it in Termux (a Linux emulator for Android) using the vim code editor.

https://github.com/dobrous155/py-to-apk-with-Google-Colab/tree/main

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34932217)