# How to use PIL code in an android application code?

Tags: java, android, python, python-imaging-library

I know there is [Jython](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html) and there is [android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). and I know how to use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) in a PC.

I would like to create an Android app that runs this code from [here](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/introduction.htm):

```
def roll(image, delta):
    "Roll an image sideways"

    xsize, ysize = image.size

    delta = delta % xsize
    if delta == 0: return image

    part1 = image.crop((0, 0, delta, ysize))
    part2 = image.crop((delta, 0, xsize, ysize))
    image.paste(part2, (0, 0, xsize-delta, ysize))
    image.paste(part1, (xsize-delta, 0, xsize, ysize))

    return image
```

1. How do I run python code in the Android Java application source code?
2. How do I run PIL python code in the Android Java application source code? which means how to add the PIL lib to the project?
3. Can I make a whole python application to android to upload on the Market?

Comment: What you're asking can't be done easily, I'm afraid. You're just going to have to bite the bullet and port that code to use Android's Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Jython on Android.

Comment: This is not true because there is Scripting Layer for Android http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/ and others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-any-way-to-run-python-on-android

Comment: SL4A doesn't have anything to do with Jython.

Comment: as soon as Jython is Python subset I think there is no real difference in this case

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure Jython is the right choice, one should consider running python in his java Android application: [Is there a way to run Python on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-any-way-to-run-python-on-android)