# Writing python code on android

Tags: android, python

I recently got a android tablet (nexus 7) and would like to be able to write python programs on it (not for it) without access to the internet or needing to access any other device to run the program.
If somebody could suggest an app, or tell me how to set it up, it would be great.
If however, someone could suggest an app that works with a different language, that would also be nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to run Python on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-on-android)

Comment: @saver: there's a difference between (a) writing a Python program on a desktop computer and later running it on an Android device, vs. (b) writing a Python program on an Android device and running it directly on the same device without needing to access any other device to run the program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to be able to run a Python interpreter on the device, use SL4A.

http://www.github.com/damonkohler/sl4a

The best editor I've used is DroidEdit.  I actually forked out the $2 for the pro version.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.droidedit.pro&hl=en

Comment: To the OP....I think these are going to be your best bet. Unless there is some obscure project out there specifically for creating py projects on a device I think your stuck with this guys suggestions. Unless some one wants to prove otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

The best offline IDE I ever use is [Pydroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid).
I love it's feature to easy share on Pastebin.

Answer (score 3):

If you are comfortable doing Python development/testing on the command line, you could follow [these instructions](http://tinyrobot.co.uk/blog/python-in-terminal-ide-for-android/) to get Python running in [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside)

Answer (score 2):

There is an awesome [QPython](http://qpython.com/) project here. You may just install [the application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hipipal.qpyplus&hl=en) from play market and enjoy Python coding everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Recently tried [Pydroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3), the best IDE on Android, autocompletion and code analysis works awesome, supports many libraries, much better than QPython3 that doesn't even have a pip in its third version yet.

Comment: I tried QPython3 and I can not use the nltk library in it, and so I come to find a solution and see your suggestion. I tried to run nltk on Pydroid and it's perfect. :) Thanks for your information, Sandor Rado and @Jayesh.