# Running OpenCV Python code on Rooted Android

Tags: android, python, opencv, rooted-device, qpython

I tried using QPython, but had difficulties in installing numpy, let alone OpenCV . Is there anyway I can run my OpenCV code on android? I have read this answer, [Is there a way to run Python on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-any-way-to-run-python-on-android) , however, I need to know if OpenCV is supported in particular. If not, is it possible to run it on a rooted android phone?

Comment: you *can* run python on android using sl4a or such, but no way using cv2 there (you'd have to port it in the same way, rmi calls and all). atm, java / c++ are the only way to run opencv on android.

Comment: Any documentation on how I could port it?

Comment: existing documentation would mean, someone did that before ;)