# I have a python script which i want to run on my android device. Is it possible to convert that py script into executable format for android.??

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, wxpython, python-requests

Below is my python code which i want to run on my android device. Is there 
any way for this in python or any library to convert py code to android.
I want to run this on my android phone.

```
import time
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

black=(0,0,0)
white=(255,0,0)

myDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((1110,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Animation")

SnowFlakes=[]

for q in range(100):
    x=random.randrange(0,1110)
    y=random.randrange(0,590)
    SnowFlakes.append([x,y])


clock=pygame.time.Clock()
farm=False
background_position=[0,0]


background_image=pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Abhishek_Yadav5\Downloads\IMG_1973 (1).JPG").convert()
background_image = pygame.transform.scale(background_image, (1280, 720))
```

Section2

```
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("freesans", 40)
label = myfont.render("  ", 1, (138,43,226))
background_image.blit(label, (200, 200))


while not farm:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            farm= True

    myDisplay.blit(background_image, background_position)
```

Section 3

```
 for i in SnowFlakes:
        i[1]+=1
        pygame.draw.circle(myDisplay,white,i,7)

        if i[1]>590:
            i[1]=random.randrange(-50,-5)
            i[0]=random.randrange(1110)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygame on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934370/pygame-on-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to run Python on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

QPython3 is one of your options I should think.

https://github.com/qpython-android/qpython3/releases

Download the apk and install on your phone.