# How can I execute a game made with pygame on an android device?

Tags: android, pygame

I wrote a simple game for my son using pygame. He would like to play it on an android tablet.
Does anyone one know how to achieve this? Maybe a good tutorial or tool to make an android app out of a pygame game? Or even through an emulator or packaging?

I have seen some answers to similar questions but they are years old citing e.g. pgs4a , I wonder if there has been any development.

Answer (score 3):

There is an app called 'pydroid' on playstore that might help you
It is an python interpreter for android that supports pygame as well

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to [run a program made with PyGame on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934370/pygame-on-android), but it may be difficult to do. Try using kivy instead. Kivy works relatively similar to PyGame, which is why I recommend it.

Comment: Thank you @charonum. I had seen this question and the answers dated 2014 and was wondering if maybe any one knew of any new developments or alternatives. A lot may have happened in 7 years!

Comment: @mhered They would probably have started a new question if there were any changes. I am not sure though. Consider looking at the PyGame Docs:  https://www.pygame.org/docs/ . But I recommend kivy.