# Python or Java for android app development?

Tags: java, android, python, sl4a

I have used Python for developing GUI based games.
But I am amateur at Java.
What will be better to use Python or Java to start Android App development?

Comment: Java. Python doesn't even make sense (as in it's not meant for android).

Comment: Android doesn't run python

Comment: Like they said above, Android doesn't run python. Java is the programming language for Android. You can use C++ with the NDK, but unless you plan on creating heavy 3d games, don't.

Comment: It IS possible to use Python on Android. However, that doesn't mean you should. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-any-way-to-run-python-on-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i saw this link maybe its possible

https://ep2013.europython.eu/conference/talks/developing-android-apps-completely-in-python

so far i knw you could use C#,Java script css html(phone gap) apart from using java. It be awesome if Android could be developed in many more languages so android market gets more apps and developers too.

i will also you recommend asking this kind of questions in quora.com or stackechange as this site is mostly about fixing code

Comment: There are also some videos for Kivy (Cross-platform Python Framework for NUI Development).  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdNh1e1kmiPP4YApJm8ENK2yMlwF1_edq