# Deploying PyQt5 application to Android via pyqtdeploy and Qt5

Tags: android, qt5, pyqt5, python-3.4, pyqtdeploy

Is it possible? I mean, yeah, [pyqtdeploy](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtdeploy/intro) intro page said: "pyqtdeploy is a tool for deploying PyQt applications. It supports deployment to desktop platforms (Linux, Windows and OS/X) and to mobile platforms (iOS, Android and Windows RT)."

I've installed Qt 5.3.0 for Android and all it's prerequisites (SDK, NDK, etc.). Also I made test project with simple button and label in QtCreator for testing deployment. Everything is fine. Next step was trying pyqtdeploy for making Qt project, pretty simple. But when I'm trying to build this project, linker said that there is no QtCore, QtWidget libraries. As I can recognize it, I've no static-linked PyQt libraries and that they must be compiled for arm architecture. Is it right? But then I've realised, that python library itself also must be arm compiled. And can I build this libraries from source in Qt?

Search did nothing. If this is true, why no one (riverbank, python) have no compiled libraries for arm?
Maybe I'm missunderstood something. In this case I got more global question.

How to deploy PyQt5.3 Python 3.4 application to Android with pyqtdeploy and Qt 5.3.0 for Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait for the next release of pyqtdeploy, which will probably give better instructions or include cross-compiled libraries.  The pyqtdeploy project is being actively developed.  Yes, you can use it for Android now, but you are on your own for cross-compiling many static libraries.

Comment: Any updates? I notice the pyqtdemo project still has incomplete instructions

Comment: how can we add qml and DB files to pyqtdeploy, any docs for it?