# Running python script in Android

Tags: java, android, python

Is there any python library ( .so ) I can include into my android project so I can run python scripts into my android app?

I used in past http://luaforge.net/projects/luajava/ .You add a .so and some java classes to your android app and you can run lua functions from your android app ,and  java functions from lua too.

Is there any similar way so I can get in my android app the result of a .py script?

Thanks all

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to run Python on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-on-android)

Comment: I saw it before asking , but there are response that instruct you to install a apk and run code inside that or thre are tons of .so that are added and i just need  something small that do not fill all my memory , smth like luajava.so if possible.Just to run py scripts ,to get data from url and some string operations ,I;m not interested in displaying dialog boxes from python.Something that dnt use to much memory would be great...