# SDN and Android

Tags: android, sdn

I'm working on setting up an SDN controller on an android device. Sadly, there seems to be very little out there on finding a way to get this type of software shoehorned into place. Even some suggestions on where else to search for information would be a great help.

Comment: What controller? Opendaylight? Beacon? What have you tried? The more specific you are, the easier it is to actually answer your question.

Comment: Not sure what your goal is but If I were you I would setup a server on a cloud or somewhere cheap and have all the mininet and ryu setup in there. Then I would use the android to  monitor, configure, stop,start. It would be more for educational purposes though. I'm down contribute in this.

Comment: Since yesterday, I'm on to trying to get Libfluid to work. Most of its 'how-to' page makes sense.
The basic goal is a kind of ad-hoc network between wireless devices and then using SDN to control the system. All of this is brand new to me, and I'm looking for any kind of input, since there's just so much info out there. Thanks for all the comments so far!

Comment: Thanks for all the input, everyone. It's my first attempt at even describing my project here. I finally got LibFluid to load on android and and experimenting with those libraries. I'm always looking for ideas, and I appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

But to answer your question, I would say any Java based controller may be easier to export to android devices. However, apparently there are ways to run python too. 
Have a look at these: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906242/run-java-project-on-android
[Is there a way to run Python on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-on-android)

Then try to see if any of the controllers like to be exported to android platform. I think this is good start.

Answer (score 0):

For the first step, I think you can try ryu or floodligt. Ryu is a python based controller, and floddlight is simple java based controller