# what are some free hosting servers to support Python

Tags: python, cgi, server-side-scripting

I am trying to make an mobile application which requests the server to run the script, and then the python script does some scraping and returns the data to the application.

for testing purposes i have went through some free servers like `000webhost.com` , `Hostinger` and `Freehostia` but they doesn't seem to support python.

So.. any help with that?

**NOTE**
I've went through `SL4A` and `Kivy` , but i want to approach this problem froma different way

Comment: AWS has a free tier.

Comment: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/    They also natively support flask, which seems like a good tool for what you are wanting to do.

Comment: @josliber how would you define this question then? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-on-android)

Comment: same goes for @martineau

Comment: Thanks a lot @SteveJ i needed it

Comment: @PaulNicolashunter asking for hosting server recommendations is off-topic for our site. The site's standards for what is on-topic have changed over the last 9 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use heroku to deploy my MessengerBot, so I vouch for it. Its simple to setup and easy to use.

Comment: thanks i'll have a look at it

Comment: it's great, i looked up and found that `pythonanywhere` too fulfills the purpose. which one do you think is better?