# Exporting sklearn random forest Python model to Android

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pickle, random-forest, pmml

Can you use a Python trained model sklearn (random forest) in Android (Java).

I need to use it to predict values in real time and a server isn't an option here.

Comment: Maybe [this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/101754/3374996). But I would recommend you look into PMML

Answer (score 0):

You've already answered your question by tagging it with the "pmml" tag - export Scikit-Learn's Random Forest model into PMML data format using the [SkLearn2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) package, and then import/optimize and score it on Android OS using [JPMML-Model](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-model) and [JPMML-Evaluator](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator) libraries.