# Access Python module from Android(JAVA) & iOS(objective c)

Tags: android, python, ios, java-native-interface

Noob alert!! I have a python module which contains my core functionality. I want to use it in my android app and iOS app. IS it possible to convert python module to android supported sdk or library dependency? If not, to what should I convert my module to support both iOS and Android? I don't even know if I am thinking in the right direction. Can someone help me pointing in the right direction on how to achieve this, a tutorial would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this question: [Is there a way to run Python on Android? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189603/4575580)

Kivy For Python: [Kivy](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android)