# Run python code right out of github on phone

Tags: android, python, github

Is there any mobile python IDE that let you get download code from GitHub directly into the app? In fact, IDE would be an overkill - I don't need to code in the app, just need to run code as a quick demo to discuss ideas with people. My code don't launch GUIs, only console outputs.

My phone is Android, but iPhone answers are also welcome. Thanks!

**Update:**

There are a few suggestions that this may be a duplicate with [Is there a way to run Python on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-on-android). I did read that one before I asked. It is either not the solution I am looking for or I simply misunderstood it - Kivy seems to be a framework to let you develop mobile apps using python, but what I am looking for is something that I can download my github repository and let me run one python file. Or you can say I want a python interpreter on my phone that can execute code (multiple modules/packages) from a online repository.

Anyway, I tried Kivy, and I got a screen like this (not intend to go off topic like the other question did, just trying to show Kivy did not solve my issue):

[image]

*PyDroid 3* is half way what I want. It is a good mobile IDE to write some simple code in. But I couldn't find a way to download a repository in there. Copy-pasting works for those all-in-one .py files, but not practical for those code living in multiple modules/packages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to run Python on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest installing Termux and using it to run the code just like a linux terminal

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).