# is it possible to code in python inside android studio?

Tags: android, python-3.x, android-studio

is it possible to code in python inside android studio?

how can I do it.
I have an android app that I am try to develop. and I want to code some part in python.
Thanks for the help
how can I do it.
I have an android app that I am try to develop. and I want to code some part in python.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Well, there is the [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) IDE, which uses the same core base as Android Studio, there is also a Python plugin available for Android Studio that allows you to edit .py files with syntax highlighting. As for running Python on Android, this question can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-on-android

Comment: What functionality are you trying to gain with Python which you think Kotlin is missing? More than likely, there's a way to do what you're trying to do in Kotlin/Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean coding part of your Android application in python (and another part for example in Java) it's not possible for now. However, you can write Python script and include it in your project, then write in your application part that will invoke it somehow. Also, you can use Android Studio as a text editor for Python scripts. To develop apps for Android in Python you have to use a proper library for it.