# No python interpreter configure for module in Android Studio

Tags: python, android

ive created django project in android studio, i already install python in my windows, how to configure this error **"No python interpreter configure for the module"?**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking for intellij instead of android studio?

Comment: what is intellij? i am new in android studio and i have limited knowledge about it. since the documentation is too hard to understand.

Comment: Android Studio is an IDE based on intellij but more limited and you can only develop android apps (only in java or kotlin as far as I know). Intellij is more general and has many plugins to support many languages, it's not free but if you are a student you could get a license for free with a .edu email: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: mr @peprumo is it okay to use pycharm on creating android app?

Comment: I don't know much about python but I think it only would make sense if the app is then wrapped in one of this hybrid frameworks like ionic or cordova in which the app runs on a webview

Comment: I believe they removed the configuration for Python Interpreter from Android Studio lately. I was using it in the past, but now couldn't find any way to get it back.

Comment: (1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/54809908/13317858 (2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189603/13317858