# Is there any way such that I can run or link a python file or code with an android app?

Tags: android, python

I have a python file that can import a csv data and then plot a graph using the python matplotlib module. Is there any way that I can use this code as backend and android as frontend to plot a graph on an android app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to run Python on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-on-android)

Comment: Yeah ! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kivy](https://kivy.org/) library is what you want

In its home page, it is written a small description like

> Kivy - Open source Python library for rapid development of applications
>   that make use of innovative user interfaces, such as multi-touch apps.