# How to run an exe file on my android application?

Tags: python, android, mobile, exe, desktop

I have an exe file working on my desktop, I want to run it on my android mobile. Is there an easy way for it?

Comment: Android is Linux. You can run Linux binaries on it, not `exe`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. '.exe' is exclusively for Windows operating system. You need an '.apk' extension file to install in Android.

Comment: If the code is in python, what do i need to do it for android?

Comment: Other than converting your code to JAVA / Kotlin , I don't thing there is any other way. Basically you need to rewrite every line of code which can be understandable buy Android. You can build apps for Android using JAVA / C++ / Kotlin

Comment: Check this link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-on-android