# How to access the phone contacts in beeware (all names and phone numbers and make calls)?

Tags: python, java, android, beeware

I want to access the contacts, their names and phone numbers in my programs and use them in my program, and also how can I make a phone call with a number by pressing a button. I could not find this feature in beeware. Please guide me if possible, if not, how to use the java code to do this in beeware and connect to my program and exchange data with python. I will be grateful if you answer

Comment: I do not think this is covered by the *beeware* tool suite. Maybe you need to look beyond *beeware*. These could be what you need (not sure): [*plyer*](https://pypi.org/project/plyer/), [*pyjnius*](https://pypi.org/project/pyjnius/), and probably others

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try and test it and if i could i shear my answer here

Comment: But other if is possible better way please tell me

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Android -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/101754

Comment: really just i want use beeware

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/beeware/briefcase-android-gradle-template/issues/65:

> You can access any native system API using the [Chaquopy](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/python.html) bridging layer. Wrap any class you need with a `jclass` object (or get one implicitly via import), then invoke the native system APIs from Python as if they were Python methods.