# Run python script in android with arguments

Tags: python, android

I'm trying to run a python script on my phone to convert a file. I found several apps that run scripts but none of them seem to allow arguments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to run Python on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

I always used terminal emulator apps.  This is one of the more popular ones:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en&gl=US

Then you can install Python: `pkg install python`,
choose the script directory by using `cd` command,
and run it just like on PC `python script.py arg1 arg2`,
with any arguments you would want.

Comment: Play Store version of Termux is no longer supported, see: https://github.com/termux/termux-app#google-play-store-deprecated